# 1-To-M struct relationship advice *DApp Development

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, contract-design

Let's assume that I'm building a property investment DApp. I have two entities involved in the DApp. Those two entities are 1) providers and 2) investors. 
Right now, a provider is able to offer 1 property, and many investors are able to invest. Next comes what I really want to achieve. I want providers to be able to offer many properties and be able to distinct between 1) properties and 2) investments. 
 
 **How do I go about doing this? Is the best way to associate each entity activity with an ID?**

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic approach:

Entities for:

- People
- Properties
- Investments

Joins for:

- People => investments
- Property => investors

For each link:

https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-epilogue-e563e794fde

Hope it helps.